# How to use Material Design "mdl-tooltip" in a loop

Tags: php, css, laravel, material-design, laravel-blade

I am using the materialdesign libary' tooltip:
https://getmdl.io/components/#tooltips-section

I'd like to use this feature in a loop, but this won't work of course, because mdl is working with "id's"(tt4 in this example) to trigger the icon and show its tooltip.

How can I get this to work in a loop and link the right tooltip to the right icon?

Thank you so much!

my php laravel blade code:

```
                <td>
                @if ($note->text)
                    <div id="tt4" class="icon material-icons">info</div>
                    <div class="mdl-tooltip" for="tt4">
                        {!! md($note->text) !!}
                    </div>
                @endif

            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dynamically injecting the code using PHP echo.
PHP is the first thing to run so it will evaluate all the other things for you.

```
 echo "<div id="+$blah+">";
```

something like that

when you generate MDL dynamically, you might need to use this:

```
componentHandler.upgradeElements($('.mdl-tooltip').get());
```